# Set a background image on LinearLayout

Tags: android

Is there a way I could add a background image to a LinearLayout, so the button-controls would be drawn onto it?  I was trying to see if there was a way to have the bitmap as a background to a LinearLayout, but could not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the xml-Tag `android:background="@drawable/yourbackground"` or set it via code through  `setBackgroundResource(int)`

Answer (score 0):

use a frame layout and put an image view then put the linear layout like this :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chrysanthemum"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quan"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```